# Does android app's signature change if I haven't changed the keystore?

Tags: android, hash, apk, digital-signature

I've created a keystore for my app and has always been signing with it. In the app there's a verification to test if the key hash has changed (means somebody else repackaged the app). However today when I exported the apk with eclipse and installed it, the key hash has changed.

Since I've never done anything to the keystore, I suppose i shouldn't change.

Go to here to find how I get the hash.
http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-key-hashes-for-android-facebook-app

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Keystore is a collection of keys. There can be multiple keys in a keystore. If the key you selected was same, the signature must be same.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, getting two different Base64 encoded strings after some days. I confirmed the same keystore by checking the sha256 of the keystore and the apk generated. Did you find any reason or solution?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you are using the same keystore, your application's fingerprint (or hash) will not change.
If the fingerprint changes, the Play Store will also refuse your application update.

Double check that you are using the same keystore and the same key from that keystore. A common source of an issue like this is accidentally using the debug keystore instead of a release keystore.